# How do I use new line characters (\n) with command line arguments in node?

Tags: node.js, newline

I want to make a script that will treat `\n` character as a literal new line character when given as command line argument. For example if my script is `test.js`, I want to use `node test.js 'Line 1\nLine 2'` and get the output as:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

The script I used to test if this works was:

```
console.log(process.argv[2]);
```

But when I used it like `node test.js 'Line 1\nLine2'`, it gave me the output as:

```
Line 1\nLine2
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand whats stopping you? `console.log('line 1\nline 2');` prints exactly what you want.

Comment: it does when you use it directly, but when you provide the string as an Command line argument it is interpreted as just a character.

Comment: Some of this may be at the mercy of the shell or command prompt you are using and how it interprets arguments prior to passing them to your program.

Comment: I am using Linux, I tried bash, sh, and even zsh. All give the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain what's going on, have a look at the following:

```
const str1 = process.argv[2];
const str2 = '\n';

console.log(Buffer.from(str1)) // prints <Buffer 5c 6e> if '\n' is passed as an argument to the script
console.log(Buffer.from(str2)) // prints <Buffer 0a>
```

Looking the buffer values up in the ASCII table, you'll find:

```
10  0a  00001010    &#10;   LF  Line Feed
92  5c  01011100    &#92;   \   backslash
110 6e  01101110    &#110;  n
```

So as you can see the argument `'\n'` is not interpreted as a Line Feed character but literally as `\` and `n`.

To fix this, using bash you can pass the argument through `$'<...>'` [expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48121) forcing escape sequences to be interpreted:

```
node test.js $'Line1\nLine2'
```

This will print

```
Line1
Line2
```

to the console as expected.